# Can two or more 'try/catch' statements share a 'finally' statement in C#?

Tags: c#, try-catch

Can two or more 'try/catch' statements share a 'finally' statement in C#? I am trying to follow a coworker's code and it's very sloppy and unexecutable.

Example:

```
try
{
    Function1()
}
catch { }
try
{
    Function2();
}
catch { }
try
{
    Function3();
}
catch { }
finally
{
    EndFunction();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the sort of question that takes less time to write a simple test than to post a question and wait for someone to answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, each `try/catch/finally` sequence is a discrete block-level statement.  However, each `try` can have *zero, one or more* `catch` clauses followed by an optional `finally` clause.

Looking at the code, I see no compelling reason it isn't written as:

```
try
{
    Function1()
    Function2();
    Function3();
}
finally
{
    EndFunction();
}
```

As Jordão mentions, empty (uncommented) catch handlers are a terrible practice.  And there's no reason for splitting out the various function calls into separate `try` blocks if you want them all handled by the same `finally` block.

Comment: The given code is akin to VB's `On Error Resume Next`, this code is functionally different.  If Function1 errs, the given block will execute Function2 & Function3; this will stop.

Comment: I know it's different, and I should have stated as such.  However, control-flow should not be implemented via exception logic.  So if the behavior you mention is desired, the code is poorly written.  (To put it another way, if you are catching expected exceptions, then the exceptions aren't exceptional and thus exceptions should not be used for this purpose.)

Answer (score 7):

The finally is only applicable to the *last* `try` in your example.

It's also not a good idea to have empty `catch` blocks, as it's akin to swallowing bugs.

Comment: (because the finally is optional)

Answer (score 5):

Sure. Just wrap the try/catch with one try/finally.

```
try
{
    try
    {
    }
    catch ...
    try
    { }
    Catch ...
 }
 finally 
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the finally only applies to the last try/catch block.

Answer (score 1):

if you are expecting specific exception from each call you can chain your catch statements

```
try
{
 Function1();
 Function2();
 Function3();
} catch(Func1Exception e1) {

} catch (Func2Exception e2) {

} catch (Func3Exception e3) {

} finally {
  //shared finally
}
```

another option is use an to track which function has executed

```
var functionExecuted = -1;
try
{
 Function1();
 functionExecuted = 1;

 Function2();
 functionExecuted = 2;

 Function3();
 functionExecuted = 3;
} catch(Exception e) {

} finally {
  // functionExecuted indicates the last executed function
}
```

another option is to write a finally function that is called from the individual finally's -- but that strikes me as weird.